# Content Management System for Documentation of a Research Project

Tags: content-management-system, wiki

I am working on documentation of a Research Project at my college.
I am searching for a mediawiki style content management system with good user privilege features so that the sections of wiki accessible to the wiki user will map to their privilege level.

Users who do not have an account will not be able to access the documentation. I am not sure mediawiki has that feature. Please suggest some options to select from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DokuWiki seems pretty interesting for this purpose. Tested it myself and it is quite simple to install and manage.

http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki

Comment: Really depends on what exactly you need. I can only point you to the access control list description of DokuWiki http://www.dokuwiki.org/acl.

But I'm quite certain that this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look for SharePoint 2010 Foundation which is free of cost
http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/Pages/Licensing-Details.aspx.